# Azure App Service - Setting up Deployment Slots for existing App Service

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment-slots

I have an existing App Service created in Azure, which has a connection string linking to the database, 'Easy Tables' configured, and a whole bunch of custom API methods and table definitions done via the 'App Service Editor'.

I'm at a stage in development where I need to use deployment slots, in order to have separate environments for development, test, and eventually live.

On creating a deployment slot, I have the option of 'Configuration Source' - where I can clone an existing application.
I select my existing app when I choose this option, however my Easy Tables or API configurations are not carried over with it, and it appears I need to set them up again?

Considering that I already *do* have everything set up in the App Service, how can I transfer the Easy Tables and API methods over to the new deployment slot *without* recreating each file one by one.

The end goal that I am trying to achieve is an exact duplication of my current web app - pointing to a separate database, having it's own collection of API calls and easy tables - all using the existing app as a starting point, with a URL different to the existing app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> however my Easy Tables or API configurations are not carried over with it, and it appears I need to set them up again?

Answer in short **yes**. According the [Set up staging environments in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing), we could know the if we choose WebApp as **Configuration Source**, it copies the configuration info such connectionstring setting, appsetting etc. not the content of the WebApp.

> There is **no content** after deployment slot creation. You can deploy to the slot from a different repository branch, or an altogether different repository. You can also change the slot's configuration. Use the publish profile or deployment credentials associated with the deployment slot for content updates. For example, you can [publish to this slot with git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git).

Comment: So far - all the server-side stuff has been done through the Easy Tables interface, or the App Service Editor interface - at this point, _none_ of the code has been done in a git repository or 'offline'/away from Azure. I seem to be having trouble taking what _exists_ and putting that into a repository - is this not possible?

Comment: I have found a solution to downloading the project, but I'm just unsure of how to set up a solution that can be properly read by deploying via a git branch.

Comment: Have you referenced [publish to this slot with git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git)?

Comment: I'll be checking through that at work tomorrow - in the meantime, thanks for setting me on the right track!